# link textboxes by line, display mindmap

Tags: css

I have to display simple mindmap, to do it I have to display simple textboxes and link them with some line, but I dont have any idea how to do it, is there any css property that helps me ?

Comment: In short, no. You need to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: Is there a reason to use textboxes? That is, do you need boxes where the user can enter text? And do you need this for a single page with fixed structure and layout, or as a general, parameterizable solution?